# How to fix SQLException in the Catch Statement?

Tags: java, swing, postgresql, intellij-idea

This program is about auto complete. When I type something to the `textfield`, a list of suggestions will appear.

I make the method `onWordUpdated()` for a list of suggestions from the DB when I type something to the `textfield`.

Now, the problem is I have this error:

```
exception java.sql.SQLException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

I made a comment in the code so that you will know which line.

Could someone help me how to fix this?

thanks..

I have this code:

```
public void onWordUpdated(final String toComplete)
  {
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          final List<Suggestion> suggestions = suggestor.getSuggestions(toComplete);
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
          {
            public void run()
            {
              try
              {
                suggestionWidgetModel.clear();
                for (Suggestion suggestion : suggestions)
                  suggestionWidgetModel.addElement(suggestion.getCaption());
                if (!suggestions.isEmpty())
                  suggestionWidget.setSelectedIndex(0);
              }
              catch (SQLException e) // This line is my problem, Could someone help me how to fix this? Thanks.. 
              {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          });
        }
        catch (SQLException e1)
        {
          onSqlError(e1);
        }
      }
    }, "onWordUpdated").start();
  }
```

Comment: please use code for illustration purposes only. it is hard to understand the question that has code not related to the problem and a question hidden inside the comments.

Comment: What does the SQLException say?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? What do you expect your code to do, and what is it actually doing? If it's throwing an exception that you don't expect can you provide more information about what it's saying?

Comment: exception java.sql.SQLException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: Why you want to catch only `SQLException` there, try changing it to just `Exception` and see what it says

Comment: @Arpit - that is terrible advice.  Catching `Exception` is almost always a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is simply telling you that you don't need to catch that exception at that point.

`SQLException` is a checked exception, which means that your code should only see it if you either explicitly throw it, or you call a method that declares it in its `throws` clause.  Neither of these is true for the code in that particular try/catch block.

You should be able to just get rid of the inner try/catch block and probably the outer one too.

---

<sup>IIRC, it is theoretically possible to see checked exceptions that haven't been declared, but this unlikely to arise unless you take special steps to make it happen.</sup>

Comment: When I try to remove the try/catch block, an error appeared saying:                                                               Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: That is a different problem.  You don't have the Postgres drivers on your classpath.

Comment: @Stephen - "it is theoretically possible to see checked exceptions that haven't been declared" - I'm curious about this. Can you explain or link to a discussion that elaborates?

Comment: @Kublai:  It is possible to throw a checked exception by abusing generics.  It basically comes down to creating a generic method that takes and then throws the exception but basing the throws clause on the type parameter (which is legal) and doing an unchecked cast to the type parameter.  Then you invoke the function like `MyLibrary.<RuntimeException>uncheckedThrow(new IOException())`.  Here's a concise example: http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/29/sneaky-throw/

Answer (score 7):

Java has two types of [exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html): unchecked (those that inherit from `RuntimeException` or `Error`) and checked (all others that inherit from `Exception`).

A checked exception has the following properties:

- If a block of code throws one, it must be caught in a catch block or the method must declare that it may throw that type of `Exception`.
- If some code calls a method that `throws SomeException`, that code must also be in a try-catch or its method must also specify `throws SomeException`.

Because of the first two checks, the compiler can detect whether a checked exception can actually be thrown in a certain block of code.  As a result, this leads to a third property:

- If the catch clause of a try-catch block declares an `Exception` type that cannot occur in the `try` block, then a compile error is generated.  The compiler does this primarily to tell you that you've made an error: you're dealing with an exception that will never be thrown.

[`SQLException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) is a checked exception so it is subject to those rules.  None of the lines of code (or the methods they call) in the try block below can ever throw a `SQLException` so the compiler tells you via a compile error.

```
try {
    suggestionWidgetModel.clear();
    for (Suggestion suggestion : suggestions)
        suggestionWidgetModel.addElement(suggestion.getCaption());
    if (!suggestions.isEmpty())
        suggestionWidget.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
catch (SQLException e) // This line is my problem, Could someone help me how to fix this? Thanks.. 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When I try to remove the try/catch block, an error appeared saying: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver